# pyspark select/filter from a dataframe multiple conditions

Tags: pyspark

I have two dataframes
d1:

| item | c1 | c2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| A | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| B | 1 | 3 | 8 |

d2:

| c1 | c2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |

I want to use some function to get this

| item | c1 | c2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| B | 1 | 3 | 8 |

check if d1.c1=d2.c1 d1.c2=d2.c2 d1.value=d2.value find those rows and drop others.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually what I want is find the item has max value with same c1 and c2. I used groupby to get d2. I was stuck to get item column back

Comment: You want to do a left semi join: `result = d1.join(d2, <your condition>, "leftsemi")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comment, one way to go about solving this without a join would be to use window function, partition by `c1, c2` and then order by `value` desc and apply row number and choose the first row to get the row with the maximum `value` for same `c1, c2`.

If you expect to have multiple rows containing the maximum value and want to select all such rows then you will apply `rank` instead of `row_number`.

### Working Example (row_number)

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc

df = spark.createDataFrame([{"item": "A", "c1": 1, "c2": 2, "value": 3}, {"item": "B", "c1": 1, "c2": 2, "value": 4}, {"item": "A", "c1": 1, "c2": 3, "value": 5}, {"item": "B", "c1": 1, "c2": 3, "value": 8}])

window_spec  = Window.partitionBy("c1", "c2").orderBy(desc("value"))

df.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(window_spec)).where("row_number = 1").drop("row_number").show()
```

#### Output

```
+---+---+----+-----+
| c1| c2|item|value|
+---+---+----+-----+
|  1|  2|   B|    4|
|  1|  3|   B|    8|
+---+---+----+-----+
```

### Working Example (rank)

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc

df = spark.createDataFrame([{"item": "A", "c1": 1, "c2": 2, "value": 4}, {"item": "B", "c1": 1, "c2": 2, "value": 4}, {"item": "A", "c1": 1, "c2": 3, "value": 5}, {"item": "B", "c1": 1, "c2": 3, "value": 8}])


window_spec  = Window.partitionBy("c1", "c2").orderBy(desc("value"))

df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(window_spec)).where("rank = 1").drop("rank").show()
```

#### Output

```
+---+---+----+-----+
| c1| c2|item|value|
+---+---+----+-----+
|  1|  2|   A|    4|
|  1|  2|   B|    4|
|  1|  3|   B|    8|
+---+---+----+-----+
```